# Classes and functions involved in serialization and unserialization

Tags: options

I want to know all the classes and functions(individual .php files) in a wordpress installation that handle serialization and unserialization.

Comment: http://andrewnacin.com/2010/04/18/wordpress-serializing-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress uses `maybe_serialize()` and `maybe_unserialize()`. Both of them use PHP's native `serialize()` and `unserialize()` functions. See:

http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php.source.html#l1028

http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php.source.html#l222

Both of those functions make use of the function `is_serialized()`, which checks if the variable is serialized yet. See:

http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php.source.html#l222